# you tube video does not autoplay on tablet

Tags: youtube

The video automatically plays when it's a computer, but when the website is opened from any tablet, it doesn't play.

Comment: SO is not an appropriate place for questions about applications functions. Maybe another [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) site, but definitely not the stackoverflow. And did you chose these tags --  `php`, `wordpress`, and `youtube-api`? I replaced them all by `youtube`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done. Apple doesn't allow that.

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled.

[Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)